# Getting error using cbind in lapply-R

Tags: r

Let I have a list of data frames(l1) and I have a vector (v1) which consists integers.

I want to combine v1 with each elements of l1. Let:

l1[[1]]:

```
head1
-----
4
3.2
4.1
```

l1[[2]]:

```
head2
-----
1.2
0.9
3.2
```

and let

v1:

```
head3
-----
5
4
7
```

So the resulting list(l2) should be:

l2[[1]]:

```
   head3 head1
   ----- -----
    5    4
    4    3.2
    7    4.1
```

l2[[2]]:

```
   head3 head2
   ----- -----
    5    1.2
    4    0.9
    7    3.2
```

I use the below code:

```
l2<-lapply(l1, function(i) cbind(v1,l1[[i]]))
```

However, I get such an error:

```
Error in lapply(l1, function(i) cbind(z, l1[[i]])) : 
  object 'l1' not found
```

Why do I get this error? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(cbind, l1, v1)
```

In case 'v1' is a `vector`

```
Map(cbind, l1, list(v1))
```

Or just loop through the sequence of 'l1' with `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_along(l1), function(i) cbind(v1, l1[[i]]))
```

Or use `transform` to create a new column

```
lapply(l1, transform, head3=v1$head3)
```

NOTE: Assuming that 'v1' is a `data.frame`

---

The error in OP's code occurred because it is looping through 'l1'.  Each element of 'l1' is a 'data.frame'.  So, we can use that for subsetting.  Either, we should loop through the sequence of 'l1' and subset the 'l1' by indexing or pass the 'l1' directly and create the column.